# Fragment in an Activity on Hardware Back Key press

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment

If an activity having 3 fragments a, b,c.we are moving from fragment 'a' to fragment 'c, and add to back stack. then press hardware back button, then what are the things being happen.Can any one explain the flow.which destroys first(activity or fragment), the flow which they go through like fragment onpause(), onstop(),... then activity onPause(), onStop() is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment always create  as last and as first is destroyed.
You can see all this information on this site: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

information about Activity:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html